# Selenium Nullpointerexception webelement

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import pageObjects.UserConfigElements;
public class TestLogin extends Initial {

Initial i = new Initial();
UserConfigElements ele = new UserConfigElements();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    i.initChromeDriver();
    test();
    i.close();
    i.initFirefoxDriver();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    i.FireFoxChromeLogin();
    i.sleep(10000);
    i.getToUserConfig();
    ele.primaryPhoneInput(driver);

}

@After
public void closeDriver() {
    i.close();
}
}
```

this method in the UserConfigElements

```
    public WebElement confirmPasswordText(WebDriver driver){
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("dontSendToServer-input"));
    return element;
}
```

is this the correct way to pass a webelement? i am using a public driver in another class.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("primaryPhone-input")).sendKeys("123-321-4231");
```

when i used the line above in another program it worked fine. so not sure what i am doing wrong.

but when i try the other way it gives me a nullpointerexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pageObjects.UserConfigElements.primaryPhoneInput(UserConfigElements.java:45)
    at TestLogin.test(TestLogin.java:25)
    at TestLogin.setUp(TestLogin.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read a little bit about `@Before` annotation (e.g. [What order are the Junit @Before/@After called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076599/what-order-are-the-junit-before-after-called)). It is executed before `@Test` method. You don't need to write

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    i.initChromeDriver();
    test();
    i.close();
    i.initFirefoxDriver();
}
```

Try just

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        i.initFirefoxDriver();
    }
```

Because you are calling `i.close()` two times (in methods annotated `@Before` and `@After`).